# How to get record which have min has_many rec ords(joins data)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, activerecord

user.rb

```
has_many :properties
```

property.rb

```
belongs_to :user
```

I want to get a user who have min properties like wise for max also.

I cant find any query related to that

Comment: which properties min, i.e. by which field? please elaborate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find the `user` with `min` properties you can simply do,

```
User.joins(:properties).group("properties.user_id").order("count(properties.user_id) desc").last
```

And to find the `user` with `max` properties,

```
User.joins(:properties).group("properties.user_id").order("count(properties.user_id) desc").first
```

**Note:** Because its a join operation with `properties`, so `user` with no `properties` will not appear in this query.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `counter_cache`.

The `:counter_cache` option can be used to make finding the number of belonging objects more efficient.

From [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

```
belongs_to :user, counter_cache: true
```

Then create the migration:

```
def self.up
  add_column :users, :properties_count, :integer, :default => 0

  User.reset_column_information
  User.find(:all).each do |u|
    User.update_counters u.id, :properties_count => u.properties.length
  end
end
```

Then you can fetch user which have max `properties_count`

```
User.maximum("properties_count")
```

Here is an awesome [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column) about counter_cache

Answer (score 4):

I think you can do like this by scopes

```
class User
  has_many :properties
  scope :max_properties,
    select("users.id, count(properties.id) AS properties_count").
    joins(:properties).
    group("properties.id").
    order("properties_count DESC").
    limit(1)

  scope :min_properties,
    select("users.id, count(properties.id) AS properties_count").
    joins(:properties).
    group("properties.id").
    order("properties_count ASC").
    limit(1)
```

And just call User.max_properties and User.min_properties

UPDATED:

It will aslo work like BoraMa suggeted

```
class User
  has_many :properties
  scope :max_properties,
    select("users.*, count(properties.id) AS properties_count").
    joins(:properties).
    group("users.id").
    order("properties_count DESC").
    limit(1)

  scope :min_properties,
    select("users.*, count(properties.id) AS properties_count").
    joins(:properties).
    group("users.id").
    order("properties_count ASC").
    limit(1)
```

Comment: I think you should group by `users.id` and not `properties.id` for this to work. Also, you can select `users.*` instead of just the `id` so that the returned user is usable as a normal rails record with all attributes.

Comment: @BoraMa, @Thorin   you can group by `users.id` and select only `users.id` instead `users.*` because `users.*` only support in `mysql`. `PG`  not allow to select columns other than group column and aggregate function